# Delete children in multilevel menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have table menu with column: `id`, `value`, `id_parent`.
And have multilevel menu:

```
Item0
    Item1
        Item2
            Item3
```

I want to delete `Item1` and I have his `id`.
How I can delete `Item2` and `Item3` when I delete `Item1`?
I select from table:

```
public function searchChildren($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM menu WHERE id_parent = '{$id}'";

    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

I can find `id` the first child:

```
$idChild = $this->model->search_children_id($id);
```

How can I find the rest children using a cycle or recursion?

Comment: set your constraints right https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Is this suitable for this table?

Comment: for this method must be 2 tables? I understand correctly?

Comment: It only depends on the foreign key constraint

Comment: It was look like: ALTER TABLE menu
ADD CONSTRAINT menu_menu_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_parent) REFERENCES menu (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;? correctly?

Comment: So you've discovered that MySQL has (at least historically) no recursive capability. Accordingly, options on handling hierarchical data are widely discussed

Answer (score 1):

I would create a variable function that i pass to itself by reference, probably better ways to do this, but i created a tree navigator using this method and it works perfectly

I would simply check if there is child under that id, if there is loop though them til there is no more childs, Once there then delete the id

this is non-tested code and sort of pseudo-code, but you will get the idea

```
$DeleteIdAndChilds= function($Id) use( &$DeleteIdAndChilds){
   while($ChildId = $this->model->search_children_id($Id) != null){
       $DeleteIdAndChilds($ChildId);
   }
   //once we are here there is no more child lets delete the $Id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cuz you have an `id`, just make function delete. examp:

```
function delete_menu($id){
   $this->db->where('id_parent', $id);
   $this->db->delete('menu');
}
```

Comment: but if 10 children? 10 times to write the same thing? I need a universal method with recursion

Comment: how delete from table on id I know)

Comment: you can use mysql_trigger [mysql_trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) for that.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend a recursive function to find all of his children. What do you want to happen if there are multiple children at the same level?

UPDATE: My bad, I didn't mean to leave you hanging... Here is some code for a recursive function. It is essentially the same I use to display my menu except stripped down and refactored for your purpose.

I use pk_ID, Menu_Item, and Menu_Parent for the data columns.

I really hope this helps you.

> 1. Call the recursive function which will return a string of itself and all child Items.
> 2. Convert to an array.
> 3. Loop through the array to delete what you want.

```
$menu = rtrim(($this->getMenu(0)), ","); 
$menu = explode(",", $menu);


public function getMenu($p_parentID=0) {
  $output = "";
  $data = $this->db->order_by("Menu_Parent, Menu_Item", "ASC")->get_where("my_menu", array(
    "Menu_Parent" => $p_parentID,
  ));
  foreach ($data->result() as $row) {
    $output .= "{$row->Menu_Item}<br>";
    if ($this->hasChildren($row->pk_ID)) {
      $output .= $this->getMenu($row->pk_ID);
    }
  }
  return $output;
} # END FUNCTION getMenu


public function hasChildren($p_value=0) {
  $data = $this->db->get_where("my_menu", array(
    "Menu_Parent" => $p_value
  ));
  $result = $data->num_rows();
  return $result;
} # END FUNCTION hasChildren
```

Comment: I don't know how to write this

Comment: delete their too